# How do I change the below graph query to get only service message from past 7 days?

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api

How do I change the below graph query to get only service message from past 7 days?

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/admin/serviceAnnouncement/messages
```

I am trying to get data from past 7 days. Every time I run this query I should get data from past 7 days only.

Answer (score 0):

There is no comment in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceupdatemessage?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) which properties on `serviceUpdateMessage` resource type support filtering but you can try one of the below queries with `$filter` parameters.

```
GET /v1.0/admin/serviceAnnouncement/messages?$filter=startDateTime gt 2022-11-29T12:00:00Z
GET /v1.0/admin/serviceAnnouncement/messages?$filter=startDateTime ge 2022-11-29T12:00:00Z
GET /v1.0/admin/serviceAnnouncement/messages?$filter=endDateTime gt 2022-11-29T12:00:00Z
GET /v1.0/admin/serviceAnnouncement/messages?$filter=endDateTime ge 2022-11-29T12:00:00Z
```

Documentation:

[Filtering on dates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter#for-single-primitive-types-like-string-int-and-dates)